# RenderdataTable as shiny module

Tags: r, datatable, module, shiny, dt

I have created the following shiny module, but it does not work, since it gives the error: 
Warning: Error in datatable: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)
Stack trace (innermost first)

```
outputTableInput <- function(input, output, session, the_data){

  ns <- session$ns

  df = reactive({
    return(as.data.frame(the_data()))
  })


  DT::renderDataTable({
    df
    },rownames = FALSE,
    options = list(
      dom = 'tip',
      language = list(info = ''),
      scrollY = '300px', 
      paging = FALSE ,
      initComplete = JS(
        "function(settings, json) {",
        "$(this.api().table().header()).css({
        'height': '80%',
        'font-size': '75%' ,
        'background-color': '#FF0000', 
        'color': '#fff'});",
        "$(this.api().table().body()).css({
        'font-size': '60%'})}")
      ))
}
```

The corresponding app is:

```
    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
          column(2, dynamicSelectInput("MovementSocietyColumn", "Select Entity", multiple = FALSE)),
          column(2, dynamicSelectInput("MovementAccountColumn", "Select Account", multiple = FALSE)),
          column(2, dynamicSelectInput("MovementImporteColumn", "Select Import", multiple = FALSE)),
          column(2, dynamicSelectInput("MovementCountryColumn", "Select Country", multiple = FALSE))
        ),
        fluidRow(
          column(2, checkboxInput("one", "Show Example", FALSE)),
          column(2, checkboxInput("two", "Show Example", FALSE)),
          column(2, checkboxInput("three", "Show Example", FALSE)),
          column(2, checkboxInput("four", "Show Example", FALSE))
        ),
        fluidRow(
          column(2,
                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.one==true", dataTableOutput("table1"))),
                                  #wellPanel(id = "tPanel",
                                  #          style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 150px",
                                  #          dataTableOutput("table1")))),
          column(2,conditionalPanel(condition="input.two==true", 
                 dataTableOutput("table2"))),
          column(2,conditionalPanel(condition="input.three==true", 
                 dataTableOutput("table3"))),
          column(2,conditionalPanel(condition="input.four==true", 
                 dataTableOutput("table4")))
        )
      ),
      server = function(input, output, session){

        the_data <- reactive({
          data1
        })

        a_filter <- shiny::callModule(dynamicSelect, "MovementSocietyColumn", the_data, default_select = 1)
        b_filter <- shiny::callModule(dynamicSelect, "MovementAccountColumn", the_data, default_select = 1)
        c_filter <- shiny::callModule(dynamicSelect, "MovementImporteColumn", the_data, default_select = 1)
        d_filter <- shiny::callModule(dynamicSelect, "MovementCountryColumn", the_data, default_select = 1)

        output$table1<-shiny::callModule(outputTableInput,"table1",a_filter()))
})
```

I know that this problem has something to do with the reactive point, but I cannot figure out the point. Thank you very much in advance for any help. Here data1 is a global dataframe (we can take mycars as well).

The functions I use are the following:

```
safeSubset <- function(df, subset){

  testthat::expect_is(df, "data.frame")

  if(!is.null(subset)){
    testthat::expect_is(subset, "character")
    out<- df[[subset]]
  } else {
    message("Subset is NULL, returning original")
    out <- df
  }

  new_data<-as.data.frame(unique(out[!is.na((out))])[1:min(50,length(unique(out)))])
  names(new_data)<-c(subset)
  new_data
}


#' Dynamical Update of a selectInput
#'
#' Shiny Module: useage details at \link{dynamicSelect}
#'
#' @param id shiny id
#'
#' @return dynamicSelectInput
#' @export
dynamicSelectInput <- function(id, label, multiple = FALSE){

  ns <- shiny::NS(id)

  shiny::selectInput(ns("dynamic_select"), label,
                     choices = NULL, multiple = multiple, width = "100%")

}

#' Dynamical Update of a selectInput
#'
#' Shiny Module
#'
#' Use via \code{callModule(dynamicSelect, "name_select", the_data, "cyl")}
#'
#' @param input shiny input
#' @param output shiny output
#' @param session shiny session
#' @param the_data data.frame containing column of choices
#' @param column The column to select from
#' @param default_select The choices to select on load
#'
#' @seealso \link{dynamicSelectInput}
#'
#' @return the_data filtered to the choice
#' @export
dynamicSelect <- function(input, output, session, the_data, default_select = NULL){

  ns <- session$ns

  ## update input$dynamic_select
  observe({
    shiny::validate(
      shiny::need(the_data(),"Fetching data")
    )
    dt <- the_data()

    testthat::expect_is(dt, "data.frame")

    choice <- unique(names(dt))

    updateSelectInput(session, "dynamic_select",
                      choices = choice,
                      selected = default_select)

  })

  new_data <- reactive({
    shiny::validate(
      shiny::need(input$dynamic_select,"Select data"),
      shiny::need(the_data(), "Waiting for data")
    )

    sd <- the_data()
    selected <- input$dynamic_select

    ## will return sd even if column is NULL
    safeSubset(sd, selected)

  })

  return(new_data)

}
```

Comment: It's difficult to know if there are other problems as you have some user-defined functions in your app. One thing I noticed is your reactive variable needs to be called as a function. `the_data` should be referenced as `the_data()`. Also, what is `data1`.

Comment: I added some new information. Data1 is just a global variable for a df I use. Can take any other df as well. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `DT::renderDataTable({ df }, ...` -- df is a reactive, so shouldn't this be `df()`?

Comment: Could you show a snippet of your data as I tested it on mtcars and is working fine

Comment: I second with @ChristophWolk. I changed `df` to `df()` and it produced output with some warning message.

Comment: That is weard since I used mtcars now and it still give me the error:Warning in as.data.frame(the_data()) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
Warning in as.data.frame(the_data()) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
Warning: Error in the_data: could not find function "the_data"

Comment: See this line `return(as.data.frame(the_data()))` in `outputTableInput`. the_data is the value of the reactive `a_filter`, which is the return value of an instance of the module `dynamicSelect`. `dynamicSelect` does return the reactive that represents an application of `safeSubset()`, which returns a data frame. So at that line `the_data` is that data frame, and not a reactive or function, so you cannot call it. Remove the `()` and it works. I'm not quite sure yet why the warnings happen.

Comment: thank you very much, Christoph Wolk. The problem is (and that might be the warning) that when you removre the () you cannot update the data. You can print the first table and then there will not be any update when the input changes.